# Python variable resolving

Tags: python

Given the following code:

```
a = 0
def foo():
  # global a
  a += 1
foo()
```

When run, Python complains: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

However, when it's a dictionary...

```
a = {}
def foo():
  a['bar'] = 0
foo()
```

The thing runs just fine...

Anyone know why we can reference a in the 2nd chunk of code, but not the 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first example you are assigning to `a` which creates a new local name `a` that hides the global `a`.

In the second example you are not making an assignment to `a` so the global `a` is used.

This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

> A special quirk of Python is that – if no global statement is in effect – assignments to names always go into the innermost scope.

Comment: I wonder why they decided to describe it as a 'special quirk'? Contrast with javascript where `a = 1` automatically assigns to global scope! The only good thing about that is that you can quickly recognize garbage code by the absences of `var a = 1`

Answer (score 1):

The question is one of update.

You cannot update `a` because it is not a variable in your function's local namespace.  The update-in-place assignment operation fails to update `a` in place.

Interestingly, `a = a + 1` also fails.

Python generates slightly optimized code for these kind of statements.  It uses a "LOAD_FAST" instruction.

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that the use of `a` on left and right side of the equal sign leads to this optimization.

You can, however, access `a` because Python will search local and global namespaces for you.

Since `a` does not appear on the left side of an assignment statement, a different kind of access is used, "LOAD_GLOBAL".

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              9 STORE_SUBSCR        
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`a += 1` is equivalent to `a = a + 1`.  By assigning to variable `a`, it is made local.  The value you attempt to assign `a + 1` fails because `a` hasn't been bound yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's a *very* common Python gotcha: if you assign to a variable inside a function (as you do, with `+=`), anywhere at all (not necessarily before you use it some other way), it doesn't use the global one. However, since what you're doing is effectively "a = a + 1", you're trying to access `a` (on the right-hand side of the expression) before assigning to it.

Try using `global a` at the beginning of your function (but beware that you'll overwrite the global `a` value).

On your second example, you're not assigning the the variable `a`, but only to one of its items. So the global dict `a` is used.